# Use (scalar) variables in jsonschema to dynamically set attribute, e.g. title

Tags: jsonschema, google-deployment-manager

I am using Google Cloud deployment manager to manage infrastructure as code (IAC) and they support providing schema files for describing IAC templates. Their support of jsonschema is a bit weird - the documentation is very brief but it suggests that they support the latest version of the schema plus they require title and description to be within an **info** object.

This is irritating because I use an HTML renderer for my schemas, which implements jsonschema and therefore, it requires title and description to be set as top-level properties.

To satisfy both, I need to duplicate, e.g.:

```yaml
title: foo
description: bar

info:
  title: foo
  description: bar
```

I was hoping to just define title and description values once and then use some `$ref: "#/$defs/title"` magic but I don't think you can use this to dynamically set values like the title because this functionality is intended for schema parsers to fetch block content from elsewhere.

Is there any way I can avoid duplicating the values - beyond dynamically rendering my schema files which I do not want to do.

Comment: `title` and `description` inside an `info` property sounds like OpenAPI/Swagger. Are you sure you are dealing with vanilla JSON Schemas and not OpenAPI?  https://oai.github.io/Documentation

Comment: @Ether fairly sure but all I have to go on is this; https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas#structure_of_a_schema - either way though, I think my question still stands - is it possible to dynamically set title/description or I guess more generally, the question is, is there some way I can define/use scalar variables within the schema definition

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to use reference within json schema.
As a crude workaround you can use a script to add/replace placeholders:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/\$title/title: foo/g' file.json
sed -i 's/\$desc/description: bar/g' file.json
```